# When is OAuth1 preferred over OAuth2

Tags: oauth, oauth2, openid

**Scenario:**
I need to build a new API for a third party company who are building a tool to capture information of new users wishing to create accounts on our enterprise platform.

-x-

**My preferred solution:**

- API to be secured with OAuth2.0 client_credentials flow
- (if required) An added layer of security with Mutual TLS to validate the source of requests at a network level

However a colleague has suggested that the solution should be oAuth1.0 
(unsure of which flow he has in mind)

***His reasoning is :***

> OAuth1 is usually constrained for server-to-server authentication
>   whereas OAuth2 can be used for secure client-to-server authentication.
>   However OAuth2 can be used for server-to-server auth using a service
>   account.   The **key issue here then is that we have not established
>   authentication credentials of the end-user at the point of invoking
>   the resource API, so the third party server will be authenticating
>   against the API using a service account, not end-user credentials**

I am at a loss here, because I do not see OAuth1 as allowing us to establish authentication of the end-user in anyway.

***What am I missing?***

- It is my understanding that OAuth1 has largely been discontinued - largely due to the complexity it brings with cryptographic requirements with request signing.

***Authenticating End-Users***

If this is in fact required I see it best solved with a form of federated authorization model - Open Id with Signed JWTs 
- Sign in With Google / Facebook etc...

Where a token will have claims associated against them and be signed by a trusted resource.

(A total newbie with security best practice - so appreciate any guidance / help)

**Thanks**